# Perl: can not post xml data to web service

Tags: web-services, perl, soap

The web service accepts the xml data and returns values back in xml again. I am trying to post the xml data to the web services, without any success, I need to do it using Perl. Following is the code I tried:

```
use SOAP::Lite ;
my $URL = "http://webservice.com:7011/webServices/HealthService.jws?WSDL=";
my $xml_data = '<Request>HealthCheck</Request>' ;
my $result = SOAP::Lite -> service($xml_data);
print $result ;
```

I tried another approach with proxy:

```
use SOAP::Lite +trace => 'debug';
my $URI = 'webServices/HealthService' ;
my $URL = "http://webservice.com:7011/webServices/HealthService.jws?WSDL=" ;
my $test = SOAP::Lite -> uri($URI) 
                      -> proxy($URL) ;
my $xml_data = '<Request>HealthCheck</Request>' ;
my $result = $test -> healthRequest($xml_data);
print $result ;
```

However this is throwing the following error:

```
Can't locate class method "http://webservice.com:7011/healthRequest" via package "SOAP::Lite\" at 7.pl line 4. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at 7.pl line 4.
```

The webservice provides only one method `HealthRequest`. I am not sure why it is trying to find out the class method in `SOAP:Lite`. I get the same error for both the approach.

Is there any other method to achieve the same using Perl?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I have not tested it so just test and see what happens, you should at least not get the PM error.

```
 use strict;
 use SOAP::Lite;
 my $xml_data = '<Request>HealthCheck</Request>' ;
 my $soap = SOAP::Lite       
     ->uri("webServices/HealthService")
     ->proxy("http://webservice.com:7011/webServices/HealthService.jws?WSDL=");
     print $soap->service($xml_data),"\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the XML yourself and not delegate that task to `SOAP::Lite`, you need to let `SOAP::Lite` know what you are doing:

```
$soap = SOAP::Lite->ns( $URI )->proxy( $URL );
$soap->HealthCheck( SOAP::Data->type( xml => $xml_data ) );
```

I have my doubts, though, that this will work with your XML.

If your request really has no variable parameters, this may work:

```
$soap = SOAP::Lite->ns( $URI )->proxy( $URL );
$soap->HealthCheck;
```

PS: Are your sure that your webservice is a SOAP service?